# Inject dependencies in TypeScript / Angular to prototype

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm quite new to TypeScript and Angular 7 and I'm trying to achieve that some components of a menu show if the user has been granted permission for them (JWT token contains a role).

My idea would be to reuse the GuardServices that I have and call the method canActivate in a filter loop so that the menu returned is the one to display according to user's roles.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    public appPages = [
        {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            url: '/app/dashboard',
            icon: 'home'
        },
        {...},
        
        {
            title: 'Employees',
            url: '/app/employees',
            icon: 'contacts',
            guard: AdminGuardService
        },
        {
            title: 'Logout',
            url: '/app/logout',
            icon: 'log-out'
        }
    ];

    public authenticated = false;
    public position = 'end';

    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private router: Router,
        private auth: AuthenticationService
    ) {
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    initializeApp() {
        (...)
    }

    getAppPages(): any {
        return this.appPages.filter(page => {
            if (page.guard != null) {
                page.guard.prototype.auth = this.auth;
                return page.guard.prototype.canActivate();
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

Basically here I'm injecting manually the `authService` that the AdminGuardService requires. In the future I might need other services that have other dependencies and this method is not scalable at all. So I'd like to delegate the injection of dependencies to Angular and just call the `canActivate()` method.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) {
    }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        return this.auth.isAuthenticated() && (this.auth.roles.includes('Admin') || this.auth.roles.includes('UserAdmin'));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by injecting Angular's default injector and just getting an instance of the class with it.:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    ...
    private injector: Injector
) {
    this.initializeApp();
}


getAppPages(): any {
    return this.appPages.filter(page => {
        if (page.guard != null) {
            return this.injector.get(page.guard).canActivate();
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your end goal, there are a number of ways to approach this.

If you want to update these whenever your auth changes, then you could make that into an observable, subscribe to it, and filter the paths the user has access to. If you use an observable, then your html can async the items and update when appropriate. [I love this site](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) and learn something new almost every time I go to it. This method is how I react to changes when I'm using Firebase auth and have roles/teams/public/private etc.

Alternatively if you only care during the app init phase, you could create an injectable token (provided via factory `useFactory`), or use the APP_INITIALIZERs and give the factory method for that the providers you need. [See more on useFactory](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/08/17/using-useclass-usefactory-usevalue-useexisting-with-treeshakable-providers-in-angular/#usefactory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's more or less what I need but I'd like to get an instance of the different guards using Angular' DI injector and leverage the task to it rather than passing the references manually (as I might not need them). The Angular router might use the same technique as the Guards are passed the same way. I'm quite used to backend with Spring and there I'd `@Autowire` the ApplicationContext and then call the `return ctx.getBean(AdminGuardService.class).canActivate();`. My wish would be to achieve the same but in TypeScript/Angular